# Does Posix supply format string macros for printf/scanf?

Tags: c++, c, posix, printf

The `printf` and `scanf` families of functions in C consume a handful of primitive format specifiers that correspond to the fundamental data types – `%d` for `int`, `%llu` for `unsigned long long int`, etc.

However, there are a large number of standardized type aliases that one would like to use in practice, such as `int32fast_t`, and one cannot and should not have to know the underlying fundamental type. For the aliases in `stdint.h`, the C standard thankfully specifies a set of macros to generate the corresponding  format strings, like `PRI32`, in `inttypes.h`.

Is there an analogous set of macros for Posix? Posix has tons of opaque types like `ssize_t`, `pid_t`, `rlim_t`, `suseconds_t`, etc, which are all variations on the basic intgral types. How can one portably use those types in format strings?

Comment: if all else fails, you can always convert to `(u)intmax_t` and print that

Comment: Interesting workarounds - I never thought of that :-S

Comment: (Though going backwards, i.e. `scanf`, I'd have to do a manual overflow check and figure out what to compare exactly.)

Comment: I seem to remember that there are some typedef where one doesn't know if the type is an integer one or a floating point one (in the time handling area).  In that case, cast to long double ;-)

Comment: @AProgrammer: Yep, `time_t` is not guaranteed to be either integral or floating point. That's even in the C standard library, and I don't think there's a corresponding macro, either.

Comment: well, you can try to figure out the type by looking at converted values (`(time_t)0.5 == 0.5`) and `sizeof` - always assuming you're not on some weird architecture, of course ;)

Comment: @Christoph: I don't want a dynamic check for a static condition!

Comment: @KerrekSB: Then make the dynamic check an `assert` (disabled in Release mode), and you'll have a static guess that is backed up by a dynamic check where speed matters less.

Comment: @KerrekSB Where is `time_t` not guaranteed to be either integral or floating point? It looks to me like [POSIX calls `time_t` an integer type](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_12).

Comment: @ElchononEdelson: Right, that may have been a confusing comment: `time_t` is not specified in the C standard, but Posix does refine the requirements. This is similar to how Posix fixes `CHARBIT`, which the C standard leaves open.

Comment: @KerrekSB I think `(time_t)0.5 == 0.5` can be evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The sfio package (part of AT&T Labs' open source AST software) has functions analogous to printf and scanf which let you specify the size of the numeric value (typically using `sizeof()`) as an additional parameter. Some examples:

```
sfprintf(sfstdout, "%I*d", sizeof(intval), intval);
sfscanf(sfstdin, "%I*f", sizeof(fltval), &fltval);
```

USENIX paper: [Extended Data Formatting Using Sfio](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/usenix2000/general/fowler.html) .

Answer (score 0):

Posix guarantees that sys/types.h values are an "arithmetic type of appropriate length" with a few others as being further specified as unsigned or signed 'extended length'.  The only standards-acceptable way to output those would be to transfer it via cast in the largest appropriate language type (u)intmax_t and then output that.

Inputting them would be more dangerous (i.e., not possible in a standards-compliant fashion) as it would be difficult to guarantee your conversion to the base type didn't overflow something.