# Placeholder for ino_t

Tags: c, linux

Anyone knows what is the placeholder for ino_t type?
I'm trying to print it out using printf and have tried %d, %i, %s and others but not working.

```
printf( " file name = %s, i-node number=**%d**\n", direntp->d_name, direntp->d_ino);

warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘__ino_t’ [-Wformat]
```

Do assume my other codes are correct.
Most examples only show how to print the name, but not the inode number.
I have also searched many places.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534336/does-posix-supply-format-string-macros-for-printf-scanf

Answer (score 8):

If you know the type is integral, you can cast it to `unsigned long long`, and use `%llu`.

```
printf( " file name = %s, i-node number=%llu\n",
       direntp->d_name, (unsigned long long)direntp->d_ino);
```

Comment: Yeah. I gave almost the exact same answer. Word-by-word. At the very same time. :)

Answer (score 6):

For the record: those are called "conversion specifiers".

As far as I know, there's no conversion specifier for `ino_t`. If you are sure it's an integer, then cast it to `unsigned long long` and use `"%llu"`.

Comment: Of course +1, because I don't get many opportunities to upvote my own answer. ;-)

Comment: @jxh for the same reason. Happens so rarely :)

Comment: The safest would be, however to use `intmax_t` from [`stdint.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/stdint.h.html) and `PRIdMAX` from [`inttypes.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/inttypes.h.html). IOW, `printf("ino=%" PRIdMAX "\n", (intmax_t)direntp->d_ino);`. Or, as it is probably supposed to be unsigned, `printf("ino=%" PRIuMAX "\n", (uintmax_t)direntp->d_ino);`.

Comment: @glglgl Almost right. As you may have perceived, I was trying to come up with something that doesn't require those types, although that's admittedly not quite a valid reason since any sane system supports POSIX **and** C99, and since this is a POSIX question, trying hard to support Windows is nonsense. However, `unsigned long long` is **the** longest standard unsigned integral type, so I don't see any reason why this would be less safe than the use of `uintmax_t`.

Answer (score -2):

ino_t is typedef to unsigned long.
So the qualifier to print the same is %lu.

Comment: Would that be true for all platforms?

Comment: I am quite sure that there are systems which have 32 bit `long`s and 64 bit inums. So your answer is definitely wrong.